# curl on ubuntu 20.10 broken curl_url_set undefined

Tags: curl

This is completely bizarre.  I have never seen curl not install correctly on ubuntu using sudo apt install.  But here were are.

just trying "curl" gives
symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: curl_url_set, version CURL_OPENSSL_4

Why?  If there are dependencies why aren't they installed first as normal?  How do I fix this.  Not having curl is a serious handicap. I have never encountered this on other ubuntu installations.

Comment: what do you get from `ldd curl` ?

Comment: dunno as I upgraded kubuntu version and it went away.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Closing as upgrade of kubuntu version "fixed" it.

Comment: Answer need to be more precise to the issue. Upgrade whole OS for curl fix isn't best option. Need way to understand why curl doesn't like OPENSSL_4 . is there way to change config/install module lib to fix this?